# Wordpress Blog Not Loading properly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress blog is not loading fully.
But when i click on Home/About menu button then it loads fully. What could be the possible reason? if any one can guide me please.

Comment: It looks like a css issue, but without a link to the site or code it will be hard to know the exact problem. If it went like that after you installed a plugin, disable the plugin and see if it works again.

Comment: Your problem could be an open `<div>` somewhere. Did you change any code. If you did, go and have a look if all `<div>`s are closed with `</div>`

Comment: Please you can access on live url? so define hear.

Comment: The blog is on intranet environment, what should i define?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: Please share the page source code so that we can at least get some idea about what could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not easy to answer just watching an image, but I'll try. As someone already pointed out, It looks to be a Css issue. More specifically, it looks like the css files are not loaded.

You said that the issue is shown only at the first load of the blog, but not surfing  through the pages. 
I think the reason is that you made some errors defining the relative path of css, so the first time the path is not correct, but in other pages it makes sense.

As general idea, I suggest to inspect the web page behaviour with some tools. You can use the one embedded inside the web browser (right click and "Inspect element" in Chrome or right click and "Analyze element" in Firefox) or use some plugins (I use Firebug on Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be you would have set some background color or color for the fonts. So it may be overridden when loading the page.

The Css might not have load initially.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this issue can be

1. Check the CSS filename if it correct or typo free.
2. Check the path of CSS file through Firebug.
3. Check the order in which the file is included.
4. Clean the cache of your browser

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Proxy & Firewall

Check if your Internet connection is behind a proxy connection or firewall. Some of these tools are blocking CSS files making CSS files to not load properly. Try to clear your proxy or firewall cookies and cache, and press Ctrl + F5 to refresh your page.

Solution 2: Upgrade WordPress Plugins

Solution 3: check and press key Ctrl+u and check you page view source.here you can check if any css missing or may be css linking not properly.

I hope, it will work for you........

Answer (score 0):

There might be some error in the code of plugin or theme you used which is creating issue in the home page. Try to set debug mode true and verify if there are any errors in that page.